# byte array to file in appcelerator

Tags: file, titanium, appcelerator, iostream

I am converting byte array received from API to a file object, using below code:

```
var buffer = [73,109,112,111,114,116,115,32,83,121,115,116,101,....];//byte array
var outBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({length: size });
        for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
            outBuffer[i] = buffer[i];
        }
var inBufferStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: outBuffer, mode: Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var outFileStream = Ti.Filesystem.getFile("test.txt").open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_WRITE);
var bytesWritten = Ti.Stream.writeStream(inBufferStream, outFileStream, 1024);
outFileStream.close();
```

It takes too much time to create the file.

Is there any better way to do this in appcelerator ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code -

```
var data = Ti.Utils.base64decode(fileString);
var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: data, mode:Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var newBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: data.length });
var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer);
f.write(fileString);
```

Do let me know in case you have any query.

Thanks & Regards
Jeetendra

Comment: What is the purpose of these four lines.

var data = Ti.Utils.base64decode(fileString);
var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: data, mode:Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var newBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: data.length });
var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer);

Because data is writing in file without above mentioned lines.